# Where is my syntax error in this SQL request?

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error near `WHERE tbkay.keyword = 'ipsum'`  in the following request (using phpmyadmin):

```
SELECT tbart.articles_id FROM articles AS tbart
    LEFT JOIN keywords AS tbkey 
    LEFT JOIN articles_keyword AS tbjoin 
        ON tbart.articles_id = tbjoin.articles_id 
        AND tbkey.id = tbjoin.keywords_id
    WHERE tbkey.keyword = 'ipsum'
```

[image: My tables]

I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using an `ON` clause after each join:

```
SELECT tbart.articles_id 
FROM articles AS tbart
INNER JOIN articles_keyword AS tbjoin ON tbart.articles_id = tbjoin.articles_id 
INNER JOIN keywords AS tbkey ON tbkey.id = tbjoin.keywords_id
WHERE tbkey.keyword = 'ipsum'
```

I also changed the joins to `INNER` joins because the `WHERE` clause returns only matching rows.

If you want to keep the `LEFT` join and return all the rows of `articles` you must move this condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT tbart.articles_id 
FROM articles AS tbart
LEFT JOIN articles_keyword AS tbjoin ON tbart.articles_id = tbjoin.articles_id 
LEFT JOIN keywords AS tbkey ON tbkey.id = tbjoin.keywords_id AND tbkey.keyword = 'ipsum'
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `JOIN` should have a corresponding `ON` clause:

```
SELECT tbart.articles_id
FROM articles tbart LEFT JOIN
     articles_keyword tbjoin 
     ON tbart.articles_id = tbjoin.articles_id LEFT JOIN
     keywords tbkey 
     ON tbkey.id = tbjoin.keywords_id
WHERE tbkey.keyword = 'ipsum' ;
```

Your version has two `JOIN`s and one `ON`, hence the error.